# Modules work in python interpreter but not in iPython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Ever since I configured iPython with the ability to switch between python 2 & 3 kernels, my modules stopped importing in iPython. Is this a path issue? How do I fix it?

Comment: Are the same modules installed in both PY2 and PY3? Also are you installing modules from the command line and expecting to see them available directly inside your notebooks? You must either restart your notebook server or configure autoreload (see docs)

Comment: Yes, before I would install with pip from the command line and they would immediately be available for import.

Answer (score 1):

2 possibilities:

1. Your modules are not installed in both your Python 2.X AND Python 3.X kernels site_packages
2. You install modules from the command line but do not restart your Jupyter Notebook server. In this case, activate [autoreload](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html)

However, as stated in the docs: *"C extension modules cannot be reloaded, and so cannot be autoreloaded"*, are those modules C extensions kind of modules by chance?

Comment: No, every module I install with pip now only works in the standard python shell.